# What is wrong with my if/else statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My first time  and first project: Rock, Paper, Scissors. I have spent hours trying to figure out what could be wrong with my if/else statements. Regardless of conditions evaluated, it returns the first statement(It's a tie"). My code is as below;

```js
const computerSelection = computerPlay();
const playerSelection = humanPlay();

function computerPlay() {
  let gameItems = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  let randItem = gameItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameItems.length)];
  return randItem.toLowerCase();
}

function humanPlay() {
  let selectItem = prompt(
    "Please pick one battle item: rock, paper, or scissors"
  );
  return selectItem.toLowerCase();
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    return "It's a tie!";
  } else if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "scissors") {
    return "You lose!";
  } else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection === "rock") {
    return "You win";
  } else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection === "paper") {
    return "You lose";
  } else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection === "scissors") {
    return "You win";
  } else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection === "rock") {
    return "You lose";
  } else if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "paper") {
    return "You win";
  } else {
    return "Please play again";
  }
}

console.log(computerSelection);
console.log(playerSelection);
console.log(playRound());
```

Comment: `playRound()` you're not passing anything into the function. Do `playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add `console.log(playerSelection, computerSelection)` to the first line of the `playRound()` function. You'll see that both values are `undefined`, because you aren't passing those values into the function when you call it.

To fix, change the very last line to: `console.log(playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection));`